# PHP pass variable

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get username value to another page, but cannot. My PHP code:

```
 include("config.php");
 include('userClass.php');
 $userClass = new userClass();

 if (!empty($_POST['loginSubmit'])) 
 {
    $usernameEmail=$_POST['usernameEmail'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];


    if(strlen(trim($usernameEmail))>1 && strlen(trim($password))>1 )
    {
        $uid=$userClass->userLogin($usernameEmail,$password);
        if($uid)
        {
            $url=BASE_URL.'test.php';
            header("Location: $url"); // Page redirecting to home.php 
        }
    else
    {
        $errorMsgLogin="Please check login details.";
        }
    }
}

 <div id="login">
 <h3>Login</h3>
 <form method="post" action="" name="login">
    <label>Username or Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="usernameEmail" autocomplete="off" />
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off"/>
    <div class="errorMsg"><?php echo $errorMsgLogin; ?></div>
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="loginSubmit" value="Login">
   </form>
</div>
```

I want to get `usernameEmai`l in new php file welcome.php where I am trying `$username = $_POST['usernameEmail'];` but its not working. Any guidance would be helpful.

This is my userclass.php

```
   class userClass
{
/* User Login */
public function userLogin($usernameEmail,$password)
{
    try{
    $db = getDB();
    $hash_password= hash('sha256', $password); //Password encryption 
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT uid FROM doctorusers WHERE (username=:usernameEmail or email=:usernameEmail) AND password=:hash_password"); 
    $stmt->bindParam("usernameEmail", $usernameEmail,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
    $stmt->bindParam("hash_password", $hash_password,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
    $stmt->execute();
    $count=$stmt->rowCount();
    $data=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $db = null;
    if($count)
    {
        $_SESSION['uid']=$data->uid; // Storing user session value
        return true;
    }   
    else
    {   
        return false;
        } 
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is not working?   Is it bypassing the entire if statement?  If so then maybe you are submitting with an 'enter' instead of clicking the button?  Or is it going to `$errorMsgLogin`

Comment: if you want to use the parameter on the test.php  page you will have to add the name to the url like test.php/?name=somevalue. But it is probably better to use session

Comment: u can use session

Comment: When you say "welcome.php", are you referring to "test.php" or "home.php" (the redirect)?

Comment: `action="welcome.php"` ?

Comment: It is not bypassing, I am able to validate user and login to test.php. But I get no value in welcome.php when I try $username = $_POST['usernameEmail']; in welcome.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use php $_SESSION by inserting

```
$_SESSION["mail"] = $usernameEmail;
```

after form success
and put the start of session on the top of page

```
session_start();
```

this will save your user name email to oupout use

```
echo $_SESSION["mail"];
```

make sure that u insert

> session_start();

on the top of every page will use `$_SESSION["mail"];`

u can use this tutorial as example

```
<?php
session_start();
    if (!empty($_POST['loginSubmit'])){
        $usernameEmail= $_POST['usernameEmail'];
        if(!empty($usernameEmail)){
            $_SESSION["mail"] = $usernameEmail;
        }
    }
?>
<?php 
if(!empty($_SESSION["mail"])){ 
echo $_SESSION["mail"];
}
?>
 <div id="login">
 <h3>Login</h3>
 <form method="post" action="" name="login">
    <label>Username or Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="usernameEmail" autocomplete="off" />
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off"/>
    <div class="errorMsg"></div>
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="loginSubmit" value="Login">
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Let me try and get back to you, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First add `session_start();` to the top of you php tag.

Set the form action to `action="welcome.php"`.

Then when and where you want to send the variable do this `$_SESSION['username'] = $usernameEmail`.

And finally in the `welcome.php` add this line `session_start();` and call your variable by using `$usernameEmail = $_SESSION['username'];`, now you can use the `$usernameEmail` to do whatever you want with the username

Cheers

Comment: Thank you. Let me try and get back to you.